# How can I fill the white spaces in my graph?

Tags: r, r-sp

My code works 95% correctly but I am not sure why my graph has empty white spaces for certain states. For example Washington state has a count of 152 but it appears NULL?

```
txt <- "AK  AL  AR  AZ  CA  CO  CT  DC  DE  FL  GA  HI  IA  ID  IL  IN  KS  KY  LA  MA  MD  ME  MI  MN  MO  MS  MT  NC  ND  NE  NH  NJ  NM  NV  NY  OH  OK  OR  PA  RI  SC  SD  TN  TX  UT  VA  VT 
 34 103  78 241 789 200  18  18  13 355 210  26  36  48 119 106  57  98 104  32  81  26  92  62 136  65  34 164  10  30  16  70 107 100 109 151 150  97 113   3  90  15 158 479  68  95   7 
 WA  WI  WV  WY 
152  96  48  14 "
dat <- stack(read.table(text = txt,  header = TRUE, fill = TRUE))
names(dat)[2] <-'state.abb'
dat$states <- tolower(state.name[match(dat$state.abb,  state.abb)])
```

```
mapUSA <- map('state',  fill = TRUE,  plot = FALSE)
nms <- sapply(strsplit(mapUSA$names,  ':'),  function(x)x[1])
USApolygons <- map2SpatialPolygons(mapUSA,  IDs = nms,  CRS('+proj=longlat'))
```

```
idx <- match(unique(nms),  dat$states)
dat2 <- data.frame(value = dat$value[idx], state = unique(nms))
row.names(dat2) <- unique(nms)

USAsp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(USApolygons,  data = dat2)
```

```
spplot(USAsp['value'], main = "Armed Males with an Attack Threat Level", sub = "Count Per State", col="transparent")
```

[image]

Comment: Your `txt=` has line breaks after "VT" which means it is read incorrectly. After that you are referring to functions in packages that you must have loaded, but did not include in your code.

Comment: @dcarlson that solved my problem thank you! I just had to put the rest in the same line. I also was wondering if there was any way I could have the color ranging by 50's instead of 100's (ex --> 100, 150, 200) ?

Comment: That seems to involve specifying the `colorkey=` argument, but I do not know the specifics.